# JSON not arriving through ajax call?

Tags: php, ajax, json

This is my php file that gets my products, for some reason i cannot send $data['result_1'] through ajax though if i only have $data['result_1'] in the if statements then it arrives though ajax, what is the problem here, i cant seem to work it out?

```
require '../core/init.php';

if ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "mon") {
    getProduct();
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "tue") {
    getProduct();
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "wed") {
    getProduct();
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "thu") {
    getProduct();
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "fri") {
    getProduct();
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "sat") {
    getProduct();
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "sun") {
    getProduct();
}


function getProduct() {
    $data['result_1'] = '';
    $weekday = $_POST['weekbtn'];
    $preorders = DBPDO::getInstance()->get('standardorder', array(
                        array('dayOfWeek','=', "'$weekday'" ),
                        array('customerId','=', $_SESSION['customer_id'] ),
                        array('completed','=', 0 )
                ));
    foreach ($preorders->results() as $preorder) {
        $data['result_1'] .= ''$preorder->imageName;'';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
$(document).on('click', "input[name=weekbtn]", function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var action = $(this).attr('value');

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "php/standingproduct.php",

            data: {

                weekbtn: action

            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {

                alert(data.result_1);

                $("#otheritems").html(data.result_2);

            }

        });

});
```

Comment: Have you got any `error`?? and where you stuck??

Comment: No errors that i can visually see. The issue is sending my $data['result_1'] value when its in a foreach loop. For example when i have $data['result_1'] value outside loop then ajax will alert it. Right now its not.

Comment: When i change mon to GET and test it the json displays on the php file, but its not arriving in ajax.

Comment: You should declare `$data = array();` in your PHP

Comment: try with `getProduct($_POST['weekbtn'])`; and function name `function getProduct($weekday)`

Comment: @saty can you write why this would work? I tested it an it fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your `$_POST['weekbtn']` into your `getProduct()`. You does't call your function directly . so you need to pass parameter into it.

```
<?php
require '../core/init.php';

if ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "mon") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "tue") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "wed") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "thu") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "fri") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "sat") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}
elseif ($_POST['weekbtn'] == "sun") {
    getProduct($_POST['weekbtn']);
}


function getProduct($weekday) {
    $data['result_1'] = '';
    $preorders = DBPDO::getInstance()->get('standardorder', array(
                        array('dayOfWeek','=', "'$weekday'" ),
                        array('customerId','=', $_SESSION['customer_id'] ),
                        array('completed','=', 0 )
                ));
    foreach ($preorders->results() as $preorder) {
        $data['result_1'] .= ''$preorder->imageName;'';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: *You need to pass your $_POST['weekbtn'] into your getProduct().* — Why? `$_POST` is a superglobal. The function was already accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

1. You don't need all those conditions. You can have just one condition that compares the value of the button and run the function.
2. Since the function is the same for all of the possible conditions, we can just call it once - per that one condition mentioned above.
3. I would advise that the function should only return the value.

   ```
   require '../core/init.php';

   $weekday = $_POST['weekbtn']; //Consider adding a sanitization function over here.
   $weekbtn_allowed_values = array('mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun');
   if(in_array($weekday, $weekbtn_allowed_values)) {
       $return = getProduct($weekday);
       echo json_encode($return);
   }
   exit();



   function getProduct($weekday) {
       $data['result_1'] = '';
       $preorders = DBPDO::getInstance()->get('standardorder', array(
                           array('dayOfWeek','=', "'$weekday'" ),
                           array('customerId','=', $_SESSION['customer_id'] ),
                           array('completed','=', 0 )
                   ));
       foreach ($preorders->results() as $preorder) {
           $data['result_1'] .= $preorder->imageName; //Why you have those quotes before?
       }

       return $data['result_1'];
   }
   ```

Comment: Would this be recomended way even if the $data will be html?

Comment: If it's that kind of output, i'll consider `echo`-ing it from the function, but still leave `exit()` outside. The main idea of a function is that you might want to use its logic elsewhere again.

Comment: **NOTICE:** if it's an HTML output - why do use `json_encode` it? you should encode data structures, like arrays and use your JS to handle the HTML manipulation,

Comment: Well i was having trouble sending HTML through ajax and after research i found this method which ended up working. What would you suggest would be a better method?

Comment: Send an json encoded array (aka data) through ajax, in your `success` event write a js code that handles the data and update the `DOM` with the desired html structure. This approach would be faster since you're sending less "data" (just an array, not a bunch of html codes) on the request.

Comment: i will take a look at optimising my code tomorrow cheers, i was trying to get it to work tonight without luck with that code but ill check tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
    Parse the response to JSON after getting response.
    So here is the updated code :

```
$(document).on('click', "input[name=weekbtn]", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/standingproduct.php",
            data: {
                weekbtn: action
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                data=JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data.result_1);
                $("#otheritems").html(data.result_2);
            }
        });

});
```

Option 2: Also you can assign dataType : jsonp
    if you assign dataType as jsonp then no need to parse response.

Comment: 1. By specifying `dataType: "JSON"`, jQuery will parse it for you. So that won't work because it is already parsed. 2. The service is returning JSON, not JSONP. Telling jQuery to expect JSONP will break it completely.